# why postgres functions returns result in one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-function, set-returning-functions

I have a simple PostgreSQL function which I aspect should return values into separate columns `-115` and `101000005458E6258...` but it returns one column where two values are separated by a comma `-115,101000005458E6258...`. What is wrong with my function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_direction()
RETURNS TABLE(direction integer, geom geometry)             
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY SELECT 
    heading-lag(heading) over (order by time) AS direction, a.geom AS geom 
    FROM public.mytable a 
    WHERE reg='125123' 
    GROUP BY heading, a.geom , a.time;
END; $$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I call the function

```
SELECT public.get_direction();
```

Thank you.

Comment: And you should call it like this: `select * from get_direction();`.

Comment: It is a table function, so it should be used like a table in an SQL statement.

Comment: Beginner error. Thank you for help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the result as a set of columns, then you need:

```
SELECT * FROM public.get_direction();
```